# properties are not setting on custom directive in angular js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I was creating custom directives in angular js. I am getting an error in applying the css or another effect on custom directive class.What I want, When i click on anchor link than it pick the attribute value and give the effect of css to picked element. I am new in angular js. Please help me to sort out this issue.

Here is the code

```
medicalApp.directive('customModel', function($parse){
    return{

         link: function(scope, element, attrs){

             element.bind('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
               scope.hrefval=  element.attr('data-href');
                scope.hrefval.css('background-color', 'white');
            });  
        }
    }
});

<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-href="#ndcadd_bill" custom-model>
          <label><i class="fa fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
          <span>Add New</span> </a>
<div id="ndcadd_bill"><h1>Want to effect of css here not on link</h1></div>
```

Browser is showing me issue in this property  **`.css('background-color', 'white');`**

I was creating custom directives in angular js. I am getting an error in applying the css or another effect on custom directive class.What I want, When i click on anchor link than it pick the attribute value and give the effect of css to picked element. I am new in angular js. Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set style on element and not on the attribute

```
scope.hrefval=  element.attr('data-href');
//scope.hrefval.css('background-color', 'white');
element.css('background-color', 'white'); //I think this is what you need
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I want to set style to Attribute value. Not on the element.

Comment: Styles are always set on the element not on the attributes of an element. However you can assign a "Value" to the attribute by using {{myVariable}} syntax and a $scope.myVariable = "my val" in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use **element.css** insted of **scope.hrefval**

```
element.css('background-color', 'white');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will solve your problem

```
element.css('background-color', 'white');
```

here is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Balajivaishnav/jYQc6/273/

Answer (score 0):

For this we need to make it angular element using angular.element

```
medicalApp.directive('customModel', function($parse){
    return{

         link: function(scope, element, attrs){

             element.bind('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
               scope.hrefval=  element.attr('data-href');
                var refval= angular.element('scope.hrefval');
refval.css({
'background-color': 'white'
});
            });  
        }
    }
});

<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-href="#ndcadd_bill" custom-model>
          <label><i class="fa fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
          <span>Add New</span> </a>
<div id="ndcadd_bill"><h1>Want to effect of css here not on link</h1></div>
```